# How to find the number of servers serving domains which end in .com?

Tags: dns, dnspython

How to obtain servers which serve domains which end in .com?
For example,
a server which serves a.com
and a server which servers b.c.com are both counted

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
import dns.resolver
answers = dns.resolver.query('com.', 'NS')
for rdata in answers:
    print( rdata )

d.gtld-servers.net.
e.gtld-servers.net.
f.gtld-servers.net.
b.gtld-servers.net.
m.gtld-servers.net.
h.gtld-servers.net.
j.gtld-servers.net.
c.gtld-servers.net.
k.gtld-servers.net.
a.gtld-servers.net.
g.gtld-servers.net.
l.gtld-servers.net.
i.gtld-servers.net.
```